# How to view pptpd clients?

Tags: linux, pptp

I have installed pptpd in my linode vps, and setup a few client accounts. The problem is how could I view current connected pptpd clients in commandline?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the command `last |grep ppp`

The above command uses `last` to display all logins of users. As all PPTP VPN are connected through ppp0 / ppp1 / pp2 / ... , you can get VPN user access history.

Sample result:

```
root@www:~# last |grep ppp
user1  ppp0         <client-IP-address>    Mon Jul  7 23:45   still logged in
user2  ppp0         <client-IP-address>    Mon Jul  7 22:59 - 23:08  (00:09)
user3  ppp1         <client-IP-address>    Mon Jul  7 22:58 - 23:01  (00:03)
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` should return the ppp[X] interface when you have a connected user. Use that with `who` and `last` (grep with 'ppp' to find out users who are connected via VPN) , and it should provide plenty of information to cross reference.